# Super product attributes sorting order in configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product

I am using magento 1.9.2.3 version.

I have three (color, contrast and size) attributes for creating the products.

when i am going to create a new configurable product system load the attributes by id like (color, size and contrast) buy my client requirements is load the by default attribute by its position like (color, contrast and size).

Can anyone let me know how can i do this?

thank you so much.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set attributes position from admin.

> Admin >> Catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attributes   >> Select
>   attributes from list >> Attribute Information >> Properties >>
>   Frontend Properties >> Position.

You can set attribute position and i will show as per sort order.

Comment: @Muneeb Ahmad Have you try this one for that.

Comment: I have the same question, but its only in the admin panel how do I change the order, when creating new item, editing new item.

Answer (score 1):

You can change position of attribute from `catalog->manageAttribute` and also you can drag and change position of attribute in product edit `association product section` **you can drag and change position of this three attribute**

Comment: i don't want to change the position every time when create new product. i want when user create new product system automatically load attribute as color, contrast and size. no need to drag.

Comment: @MuneebAhmad please change position feild at `catalog-> attribute-> Manage Attribute` and set attribute position according to your

Comment: hi, i did it but still the issue is there .

Comment: please do reindexing from `System->indexManagment`